# document.getElementById().value doesn't set the value

Tags: javascript, html

Browser is chromium (under ubuntu)

This is a chunk of code: (of course) The alert messages shows the right value. but the points 
element doesn't get the right value, it actually gets empty. Can anybody tell me why?

Here's how points element is defined.

```
<input type='number' id='points' value='0'/>
```

and here is how javascript code is supposed to populate it.

```
alert(request.responseText);

document.getElementById("points").value=request.responseText;
```

Comment: How do you determine that it "gets empty"? What *is* the value you are trying to set? Does it behave as you expect in other browsers (and which other browsers have you tested)?

Comment: Cause I see it. When I say empty, I mean no value in the input box. It contains 0 at start, when the request is done, it turns to blank field.

Comment: Your use of `.value` is perfectly valid.  I suspect the problem is that `request.responseText` is empty.  What does the alert say?

Comment: Perhaps an input type `number` cannot have non-numeric content?

Comment: the alert says 55 as I said earlier... it does return the number back.

Comment: Are you setting the value to a string, or a number? Try the other one.

Comment: My [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fKyrt/) says that, at least on chrome, you can set `.value` with a string and it gets converted to an integer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your response is almost certainly a string.  You need to make sure it gets converted to a number:

```
document.getElementById("points").value= new Number(request.responseText);
```

You might take a closer look at your responseText.  It sound like you are getting a string that contains quotes.  If you are getting JSON data via AJAX, you might have more consistent results running it through `JSON.parse()`.

```
document.getElementById("points").value= new Number(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
```

Comment: The top level element of a JSON structure must be an array or object. Hence `new Number(JSON.parse(...))` would most likely return `NaN`.

Comment: Good point on the JSON.  If it isn't an array or object, Chrome at least complains.

Answer (score 5):

According to my tests with Chrome:

If you set a `number` input to a Number, then it works fine.

If you set a `number` input to a String that contains nothing but a number, then it works fine.

If you set a `number` input to a String that contains a number and some whitespace, then it blanks the input.

You probably have a space or a new line after the data in the server response that you actually care about.

Use `document.getElementById("points").value = parseInt(request.responseText, 10);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The only case I could imagine is, that you run this on a *webkit* browser like *Chrome* or *Safari* and your return value in `responseText`, contains a *string value*.

In that constelation, the value cannot be displayed (it would get blank)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BmhNL/2/

---

My point here is, that I expect a wrong/double encoded string value. Webkit browsers are more strict on the `type` = `number`. If there is "only" a white-space issue, you can try to implicitly call the `Number()` constructor, like

```
document.getElementById("points").value = +request.responseText;
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("points").value= new Number(request.responseText);`

Comment: Your test is invalid. `"'5'"` is not a valid number.

Comment: I run that example and I get a blank field. so it's my browser?

Comment: The same issue. `"\"15\""` is not a valid number. Is it the point here?

Comment: @slashingweapon. Type that as an answer please. +1

Comment: @JanDvorak: yes thats pretty much my point. Wrong/double encoding a string, so it can't get parsed. Webkit browsers are more strict on the `type` `number`.

Answer (score 1):

**Refer below Code Snip**

In HTML Page

```
<input id="test" type="number" value="0"/>
```

In Java Script

```
document.getElementById("test").value=request.responseText;// in case of String 
document.getElementById("test").value=new Number(responseText);// in case of Number
```

Answer (score 1):

**@slashingweapon's answer in another way:**
for me this worked:

```
document.getElementById("points").setAttribute('value', new Number(request.responseText));
```

or

```
document.getElementById("points").setAttribute('value', new Number(JSON.parse(request.responseText)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clearly not with the javascript. Here's a quick snippet to show you the working of the code.

```
document.getElementById('points').value = 100;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eqTm2/1/

As you can see, the javascript perfectly assigns the new value to the input element. It would be helpful if you could elaborate more on the issue.

Comment: Although your conclusion is correct, you sometimes have to look at your crystal ball to figure out what OP might mean :)

Comment: Note the asker uses `input type=number`. You use `input type=text`

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that the author used "number" as the type. Edited.

Answer (score -2):

Try using ,

```
$('#points').val(request.responseText);
```

Comment: This is not using vanilla javascript but JQuery.